Have email in Auth0 claims
I am using auth0 of my MVC application, and I want to retrieve the email but I find it in claims and its value during execution is null.
Here is my code:

public async Task Callback() {
  var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
  if (result?.Principal != null) {
    // Extraire l’email depuis les claims si disponible
    var email = result.Principal.FindFirst(“email”)?.Value;
    var sub = result.Principal.FindFirst(“Name”)?.Value;

    if (email != null) {
      ViewBag.Email =
          email;  // Optionnel : stockez l'email pour l'utiliser dans la vue
      ViewBag.Message = "Connexion réussie avec email !";
    } else {
      ViewBag.Message = "Connexion réussie, mais l'email est introuvable.";
    }

    return View("Success");
  }

  ViewBag.Message = "Erreur d'authentification.";
  return View("Error");
}

I can recover name and nickname but not email

Hi jalil, please check if the email is in result.Principal.Claims; first, and make sure your auth0 scopes settings contain email, something like "scope", "openid profile email".
